# How can I get only one IPN instead 3 after receiving a payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, make.com

Every single payment that I receive I got 3 IPN and it makes my system in Integromat runs 3 operation, please how can I fix it to receive only one IPN?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the messages you receive, but you can change your IPN listener's code to check t[he `txn_type` variable](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNandPDTVariables/#ipn-transaction-types) and behave accordingly.